# wagtail error on upload image in richtext field

Tags: python, django, wagtail

when I try to upload image using richtext field in wagtail I'm getting a json respons

```
html    "\n\n\n\n\n<header class=\"  \">\n    \n    <div class=\"row nice-padding\">\n        <div class=\"left\">\n            <div class=\"col header-title\">\n                <h1>\n                Choose a format</h1>\n            </div>\n            \n        </div>\n        <div class=\"right\">\n            \n                \n            \n        </div>\n    </div>\n</header>\n\n\n<div class=\"row row-flush nice-padding\">\n    <div class=\"col6\">\n        <img alt=\"icon-check\" class=\"show-transparency\" height=\"512\" src=\"/media/images/3334352_01.max-800x600.png\" width=\"512\">\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"col6\">\n        <form action=\"/cms/images/chooser/1/select_format/\" method=\"POST\" novalidate>\n            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"csrfmiddlewaretoken\" value=\"ih7zcLhxbo71c0TupgUmboJ8syIolZWshK6yfECc2zzHz0wqk009wKNyDXGHt4mX\">\n            <ul class=\"fields\">\n                \n                    \n<li class=\"required   \">\n    \n<div class=\"field choice_field radio_select \">\n    <label for=\"id_image-chooser-insertion-format_0\">Format:</label>\n    <div class=\"field-content\">\n        <div class=\"input  \">\n            \n                <ul id=\"id_image-chooser-insertion-format\">\n    <li><label for=\"id_image-chooser-insertion-format_0\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"image-chooser-insertion-format\" value=\"fullwidth\" required id=\"id_image-chooser-insertion-format_0\">\n Full width</label>\n\n</li>\n    <li><label for=\"id_image-chooser-insertion-format_1\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"image-chooser-insertion-format\" value=\"left\" required id=\"id_image-chooser-insertion-format_1\">\n Left-aligned</label>\n\n</li>\n    <li><label for=\"id_image-chooser-insertion-format_2\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"image-chooser-insertion-format\" value=\"right\" required id=\"id_image-chooser-insertion-format_2\">\n Right-aligned</label>\n\n</li>\n</ul>\n            \n            \n            \n            <span></span>\n        </div>\n        \n\n        \n    </div>\n</div>\n\n</li>\n                \n                    \n<li class=\"required   \">\n    \n<div class=\"field char_field text_input \">\n    <label for=\"id_image-chooser-insertion-alt_text\">Alt text:</label>\n    <div class=\"field-content\">\n        <div class=\"input  \">\n            \n                <input type=\"text\" name=\"image-chooser-insertion-alt_text\" value=\"icon-check\" required id=\"id_image-chooser-insertion-alt_text\">\n            \n            \n            \n            <span></span>\n        </div>\n        \n\n        \n    </div>\n</div>\n\n</li>\n                \n                <li><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Insert image\"  class=\"button\" /></li>\n            </ul>\n        </form>\n    </div>\n</div>\n"
step    "select_format"
```

[image]

I'm using wagtail 2.14.2

```
pip show wagtail
Name: wagtail
Version: 2.14.2
Summary: A Django content management system.
```

and my django is Django==3.1.7
and the image chooser not working always return :

Uncaught ReferenceError: createImageChooser is not defined

Comment: Have you upgraded Wagtail recently? Often, errors like this can be a result of old Javascript files from a previous release sticking around in your browser's cache - if so, force-refreshing the page should fix it.

Comment: No I didn't upgrade my wagtail